# Does the C++ standard place explicit requirements on the vector assign function or constructors?

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Where it may be ambiguous I will be referring to the C++14 standard.

Using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector as a reference, the requirements on the template parameter `T` for a vector are relatively sparse

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

Indeed many of the pages (e.g. the one for [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)) are remarkably explicit about the requirements placed upon `T`. Sadly the same is not true for the constructors or the assign function. Is this an omission from the website or from the standard?

**Motivation**
The motivation for this question is a little complicated. I have a class `Node` representing a node in a tree. Each node has a parent (represented by a `Node*`) and a list of children (represented by a `std::vector<Node, MyAllocator>`). This last bit is where it gets interesting. In order to ensure that the `Node`s continue to point at the correct parents I implemented a custom allocator that 'preloads' each constructor call with a pointer to the correct `Node`. The code for that is as follows

```
#ifndef PRElOAD_ALLOCATOR_H
#define PRElOAD_ALLOCATOR_H

#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

/**
 * @class PreloadAllocator
 * Provides a generic allocator that is able to 'preload' some arguments for the
 * construct function. Note that these arguments are *always* loaded at the
 * front of any constructor call so modified move, copy constructors need to
 * created to match.
 * This allocator will only work with simple containers like vector that do not
 * modify the type of the allocator being used. *It will not work* with types
 * like list and map that internally represent the data in a different format.
 * This is because the constructors for these objects behave differently and it
 * is not simple to know how to insert the extra arguments into such a call.
 */
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class PreloadAllocator {
  public:

    // Standard allocator typedefs
    using value_type      = T;
    using pointer         = T*;
    using const_pointer   = const T*;
    using reference       = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type       = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    PreloadAllocator(Args&&... args)
      : tup(std::forward_as_tuple(args...) ) {}

    template <typename U>
      PreloadAllocator(const PreloadAllocator<U, Args...>& other)
      : tup(other.tup) {}

    pointer allocate(size_type count, const_pointer hint = 0) {
      return m_defaultAlloc.allocate(count, hint);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type count) {
      return m_defaultAlloc.deallocate(ptr, count);
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
      void construct(T* ptr, Ts&&... ts) {
        // First preload the constructor arguments with the allocator's
        // versions, then add on the rest, and let the default allocator do the
        // rest.
        return construct_impl<Ts...>(
            ptr, std::forward<Ts>(ts)..., std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
      }

    // Hold the arguments that we will preload into every constructor call
    const std::tuple<Args...> tup;
  private:
    // Compose the default STL allocator to use its version of allocate and
    // deallocate.
    std::allocator<T> m_defaultAlloc;
    // Actual function that does the constructing
    template <typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
      void construct_impl(T* ptr, Ts&&... ts, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return m_defaultAlloc.construct(
          ptr, std::get<Is>(tup)..., std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
      }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool operator==(
    const PreloadAllocator<T, Args...>& lhs,
    const PreloadAllocator<T, Args...>& rhs)
{
  return lhs.tup == rhs.tup;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool operator!=(
    const PreloadAllocator<T, Args...>& lhs,
    const PreloadAllocator<T, Args...>& rhs)
{
  return !(lhs==rhs);
}

#endif //> !PRElOAD_ALLOCATOR_H

class Node {
  public:
    using alloc_t = PreloadAllocator<Node, Node*>;
    using vec_t = std::vector<Node, alloc_t>;

    Node(Node* parent, int data)
      : parent(parent), data(data), children(alloc_t(this) ) {}
    Node(Node* parent, const Node& other)
      : parent(parent), data(other.data), children(other.children, alloc_t(this) ) {}
    Node(Node* parent, Node&& other)
      : parent(parent), data(std::move(other.data) ), children(std::move(other.children), alloc_t(this) ) {}

    // Copy/Move constructing is not going to give us the correct parent!
    Node(const Node&) = delete;
    Node(Node&&) = delete;

    Node* parent;
    int data;
    vec_t children;
};

int main() {
  Node root(nullptr, 0);
}
```

When compiling this code in g++ then it compiles and runs fine. However when I compile in clang I get the following error

```
In file included from alloc_test.cxx:3:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:1275:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'assign'
        assign(_Ip(__x.begin()), _Ip(__x.end()));
        ^~~~~~
alloc_test.cxx:15:55: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<Node, PreloadAllocator<Node, Node *> >::vector' requested here
      : parent(parent), data(std::move(other.data) ), children(std::move(other.children), alloc_t(this) ) {}
                                                      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:588:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '_Ip' (aka 'move_iterator<__wrap_iter<Node *> >') to
      'std::__1::vector<Node, PreloadAllocator<Node, Node *> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') for 1st argument
    void assign(size_type __n, const_reference __u);
         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:576:9: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '!__is_forward_iterator<move_iterator<__wrap_iter<Node *> > >::value' was not satisfied
      [with _InputIterator = std::__1::move_iterator<std::__1::__wrap_iter<Node *> >]
        assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last);
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:586:9: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_constructible<value_type, typename iterator_traits<move_iterator<__wrap_iter<Node *>
      > >::reference>::value' was not satisfied [with _ForwardIterator = std::__1::move_iterator<std::__1::__wrap_iter<Node *> >]
        assign(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last);
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:592:10: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument '__il', but 2 arguments were provided
    void assign(initializer_list<value_type> __il)
         ^
1 error generated.
```

So, is this an ambiguity in the standard that g++ and clang have decided to interpret differently or is it a genuine error for one of them?

Is attempting to write this sort of preloading allocator an unforgivable abuse of the standard?

*Edit: * fixed missing data members in the code snippet.

Comment: This is quite a bit of code to look through and may turn away a lot of users who could otherwise answer your question. Is a custom allocator really required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Do you really need a custom allocator? Why not adjust the children's parent in the constructor? Could be just a simple private member function that goes through `children` and updates pointer. Significantly less code => less errors.

Comment: It's true that a custom allocator could be avoidable - I was originally thinking that the children (which in my actual use are a lot more complicated) could depend on the node from which they're constructed and therefore would need that information in their constructor. This could theoretically be replaced by a `setParent` function or something like that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Holt - hmm it won't compile on my machine which reports a clang version of `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I'm not sure that I can easily dodge the custom allocator. I think the compiler error hinges on there being a difference between something being MoveInsertable and MoveConstructible.

Comment: @extiam Sorry, I wasn't compiling with libc++. The requirements for this constructor are that `Node` is `Cpp17MoveInsertable`.

Comment: @extiam According to the standard (C++17), your code is valid because `Node` is `Cpp17MoveInsertable` in a vector with your allocator. This is different from being `MoveConstructible`, which is what clang is testing apparently. IMO, you should not use this custom allocator but rather a factory, or something similar, which have the same benefits (i.e., preventing inconsistency between parents and children), while being simpler to implement.

Comment: If we trust cppreference, then a requirement for an allocator is that `construct(xptr, args)`, if present, "constructs an object of type `X` in previously-allocated storage at the address pointed to by `xptr`, *using `args` as the constructor arguments*". Your `construct` doesn't do that. For what I can find, the standard itself doesn't say "using `args` as the constructor arguments" though.

Comment: @Holt could you repeat this as an answer so I can accept it? Could you also elaborate on the factory part as I'm not quite sure how it would work - the allocator wasn't trying to solve creating the children, but rather handling what happened when they were moved.

Comment: @n.m. - and this answers the last question - "is [this] an unforgivable abuse of the standard?": Yes!

Comment: I'm not so sure to be honest. libc++ checks for `is_constructible` in its `assign`, but this requirement doesn't seem to be present in the standard. I would tentatively call this a bug in libc++.

Comment: @extiam You should provide a bit more context on how you want to use / move / copy these nodes for us to give  you design advice. Your allocator could simply be replaced by a loop in the constructors of `Node` that set the `parent` pointer on `Node` from `children`.

Comment: @Holt in terms of design advice the answer seems pretty clear: don't do this, this kind of allocator is against the standard. The loop in the constructor seems like the simplest thing to do as well.
The main question I had was whether clang was right not to compile my code which you seem to have answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be valid regarding the C++17 standard. The strongest requirements come from this copy constructor of `std::vector`:

```
children(other.children, alloc_t(this))
```

The standard says ([Table 65](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/containers#tab:containers.allocatoraware)) that this requires `Node` to be *Cpp17CopyInsertable* into `std::vector<Node, PreloadAllocator<Node, Node*>>`:

> `T`  is [*Cpp17CopyInsertable*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements.general-15.4) into `X` means that, in addition to `T` being *Cpp17MoveInsertable* into `X`, the following expression is well-formed:
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v)
> ```
>
> and its evaluation causes the following postcondition to hold: The value of `v` is unchanged and is equivalent to `*p`.

The requirements for [*Cpp17MoveInsertable*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements.general-15.3) are similar, except that `v` is an rvalue, and the post condition is different.

When looking at the error for `clang`, it seems the compiler is checking the requirements for [*MoveConstructible*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/concept.moveconstructible):

```cpp
is_constructible<
    value_type, 
    typename iterator_traits<move_iterator<__wrap_iter<Node *> >::reference>::value
```

...which are different than the ones for [*Cpp17MoveInsertable*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements.general-15.3).

---

From a design point of view, I would personally drop that custom allocator and instead update the `parent` member manually when needed, e.g.:

```cpp
Node(Node* parent, const Node& other) 
    : parent(parent), data(other.data), children(other.children) {
    fix_parent_in_childrens();
}

void fix_parent_in_childrens() {
    for (Node &node: children) {
        node.parent = this;
    }
}
```

Since  you seems to have an already correct encapsulation, this makes more sense (to me) than a custom allocator.